# Parsing the data in the JSON format

Tags: javascript

I got this JSON data as below and want to get the ip_address
and  '5865cdc5-0f8c-481b-aaa7-4adfe6cf96ae' can be any string.

```
history': {
    '5865cdc5-0f8c-481b-aaa7-4adfe6cf96ae': {
      'profile': [
        {
          'category': 'Linux',
          'time_stamp': 1489120439.877187,
          'detected_time': '2017-03-10T04:33:59Z',
          'os': 'Linux',
          'collector_type': 'dhcp'
        }
      ],
      'ip_address': [
        {
          'ip': '10.204.49.218',
          'detected_time': '2017-03-10T04:33:59Z',
          'hostname': 'pxe-dev',
          'collector_type': 'dhcp',
          'time_stamp': 1489120439.875652
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I want to get the 'ip_address' array.
Any help please

Comment: If it's guaranteed to have one key in the history - `Object.values(o)[0].ip_address`

Comment: The supplied example is not valid JSON.

Comment: @zerkms—dunno if recommending ECMAScript 2018 features in 2017 is a good idea.

Comment: @RobG who does not risk cannot win :-D

Comment: @zerkms—yep. Was also looking for the AI to convert the OP snippet to valid code… ;-)

Comment: it's not valid json format

Answer (score 2):

that is not JSON but normal 'semi' Object instead
Use

```
    //and dont use *history* var as it conflicted with global variable
    obj = {
    '5865cdc5-0f8c-481b-aaa7-4adfe6cf96ae': {
      'profile': [
        {
          'category': 'Linux',
          'time_stamp': 1489120439.877187,
          'detected_time': '2017-03-10T04:33:59Z',
          'os': 'Linux',
          'collector_type': 'dhcp'
        }
      ],
      'ip_address': [
        {
          'ip': '10.204.49.218',
          'detected_time': '2017-03-10T04:33:59Z',
          'hostname': 'pxe-dev',
          'collector_type': 'dhcp',
          'time_stamp': 1489120439.875652
        }
      ]
    }
  }

var ip = obj['5865cdc5-0f8c-481b-aaa7-4adfe6cf96ae']['ip_address'][0]['ip'])
```

or

```
var ipAddress = obj['5865cdc5-0f8c-481b-aaa7-4adfe6cf96ae']['ip_address'])
```

if you want to check the JSON, please check following and before getting vale you need to parse it back to Javascript object

```js
obj = {
    '5865cdc5-0f8c-481b-aaa7-4adfe6cf96ae': {
      'profile': [
        {
          'category': 'Linux',
          'time_stamp': 1489120439.877187,
          'detected_time': '2017-03-10T04:33:59Z',
          'os': 'Linux',
          'collector_type': 'dhcp'
        }
      ],
      'ip_address': [
        {
          'ip': '10.204.49.218',
          'detected_time': '2017-03-10T04:33:59Z',
          'hostname': 'pxe-dev',
          'collector_type': 'dhcp',
          'time_stamp': 1489120439.875652
        }
      ]
    }
  }

var t = JSON.stringify(obj)
var t2 = JSON.parse(t)
console.log('json:', t)
console.log('javascript object', t2)
```

Comment: obj['5865cdc5-0f8c-481b-aaa7-4adfe6cf96ae']['ip_address']) won't be generic because 5865cdc5-0f8c-481b-aaa7-4adfe6cf96ae can be any number

Comment: Sure kim, for that case you can iterate through JavaScript object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object